# how to configure two Nic for dns & resolv.conf &how to eth0 DNS forwards to eth1 & gw

Tags: server, networking, dns, resolv.conf

I have two NICs.

Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp    //for internet

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static   //for lan
address 20.X.X.X.X
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 20.X.X.X.255
gateway 20.X.X.1
```

1. Which gateway is default? How do I route gateway to default gateway?
2. When I run `networking restart`, resolv.conf domain name server is replaced with the DNS server of the internet, how do I configure resolv.conf?

Comment: I edited your question. I am a native English speaker, but I'm not clairvoyant. If I got the meaning of anything wrong, let me know. I had the hardest time understanding question #2, so it may be wrong. I took my best shot at answering your question for IPv4. I'll add the IPv6 part later.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you need to install a couple of things:

```
sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server resolvconf #also possibly 'radvd'
```

**Enabling traffic through you machine (IPv4):**
Ok, now let's change a setting:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Delete the # from the start of the line `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> to save.

Run `sudo sysctl -p`.

**Set address for LAN interface (IPv4):**
Unless you are 'Computer Sciences Corporation', you should not be using 20.x.x.x addresses. You could use any of the following private addresses ranges instead: 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, or the range 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 (aka 172.16.0.0/12 or 172.16.0.0 with netmask 255.240.0.0). Run

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Delete the gateway line. This computer is the gateway for the connection, so you do not set a gateway for this interface. Other computers will have this computer's address as their gateway. Change the address line to `address 10.0.0.1`. Change the broadcast line to `broadcast 10.0.0.255`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> to save.

**Set DNS server (IPv4 and/or IPv6):**
Run

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

(ignore the scary warning. /etc/resolv.conf is autogenerated, so the warning is in the  `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file so it will get put at the top of /etc/resolv.conf when /etc/resolv.conf is generated.) To the end of the file, add

```
 nameserver <ip_of_nameserver>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> and answer yes to saving the file. To finish up, regenerate /etc/resolv.conf so the changes are applied right now:

```
 sudo resolvconf -u
```

**Set up NAT (IPv4)(***shudder***):**
Enable UFW:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Make a persistent NAT rule that is restored at boot by UFW:

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

Add the line `-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE` after the line `*nat`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> to save.

**Give out addresses (IPv4):**
Let's edit some files:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf /etc/default/dhcp3-server
```

To the first file, add the following:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.254;
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers <dns_server>;
}
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> to save. In the next file, edit the line `INTERFACES=""` to say `INTERFACES="eth1"`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>y</kbd> to save. To start the address handing out daemon, run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server start
```